# Writing a new Finagle protocol

Tags: scala, networking, netty

The following is a fairly naive implementation of a [Finagle](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/) protocol that uses the [scodec](https://github.com/scodec/scodec) library for binary encoding and decoding. I'll assume something like the following SBT setup:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.twitter" %% "finagle-core" % "6.20.0",
  "org.typelevel" %% "scodec-core" % "1.3.0-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

First for an scodec import we'll need throughout:

```
import scodec.Codec
```

Next for conversions from scodec's `Codec` to [Netty](http://netty.io/) encoders and decoders:

```
trait CodecConversions {
  import org.jboss.netty.buffer.{ChannelBuffer, ChannelBuffers}
  import org.jboss.netty.channel.{Channel, ChannelHandlerContext}
  import org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.{OneToOneDecoder, OneToOneEncoder}
  import scodec.bits.BitVector

  /**
   * Converts an scodec codec into a Netty encoder.
   */
  protected def encoder[A: Codec] = new OneToOneEncoder {
    override def encode(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, channel: Channel, msg: Object) =
      ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(
        Codec.encodeValid(msg.asInstanceOf[A]).toByteBuffer
      )
  }

  /**
   * Converts an scodec codec into a Netty decoder.
   */
  protected def decoder[A: Codec] = new OneToOneDecoder {
    override def decode(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, channel: Channel, msg: Object) =
      msg match {
        case cb: ChannelBuffer =>
          Codec.decodeValidValue[A](BitVector(cb.toByteBuffer)).asInstanceOf[Object]
        case other => other
      }
  }
}
```

And then channel pipeline and codec factories:

```
trait Factories { this: CodecConversions =>
  import com.twitter.finagle.{Codec => FinagleCodec, CodecFactory}
  import org.jboss.netty.channel.{ChannelPipelineFactory, Channels}

  /**
   * Creates a Netty channel pipeline factory given input and output types.
   */
  private[this] def pipeline[I: Codec, O: Codec] = new ChannelPipelineFactory {
    def getPipeline = {
      val pipeline = Channels.pipeline()
      pipeline.addLast("encoder", encoder[I])
      pipeline.addLast("decoder", decoder[O])
      pipeline
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a Finagle codec factory given input and output types.
   */
  protected def codecFactory[I: Codec, O: Codec] = new CodecFactory[I, O] {
    def server = Function.const {
      new FinagleCodec[I, O] { def pipelineFactory = pipeline[O, I] }
    }

    def client = Function.const {
      new FinagleCodec[I, O] { def pipelineFactory = pipeline[I, O] }
    }
  }
}
```

And then the part that actually creates our Finagle clients and servers:

```
object Finagler extends Factories with CodecConversions {
  import com.twitter.conversions.time._
  import com.twitter.finagle.Service
  import com.twitter.finagle.builder.{ClientBuilder, ServerBuilder}
  import com.twitter.util.{Duration, Future}
  import java.net.InetSocketAddress

  /**
   * Creates a Finagle server from a function given that we have scodec codecs
   * for both the input and output types.
   */
  def server[I, O](port: Int)(f: I => Future[O])(implicit ic: Codec[I], oc: Codec[O]) =
    ServerBuilder()
      .name("server")
      .codec(codecFactory[I, O])
      .bindTo(new InetSocketAddress(port))
      .build(new Service[I, O] { def apply(i: I) = f(i) })

  /**
   * Creates a Finagle client given input and output types with scodec codecs.
   */
  def client[I, O](host: String, timeout: Duration = 1.second)
    (implicit ic: Codec[I], oc: Codec[O]) =
      ClientBuilder()
        .name("client")
        .codec(codecFactory[I, O])
        .hosts(host)
        .hostConnectionLimit(1)
        .timeout(timeout)
        .build()
}
```

And finally usage looks like this:

```
import scodec._, codecs._
import com.twitter.util.Future

case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)

implicit val pointCodec = (double :: double).as[Point]
implicit val pointsCodec = list(pointCodec)

def center(points: List[Point]) = {
  val Point(x, y) = points.reduce[Point] {
    case (Point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2)) => Point(x1 + x2, y1 + y2)
  }

  Point(x / points.size, y / points.size)
}

val server = Finagler.server(9000)(center _ andThen Future.value _)
```

And then we can create a client:

```
val client = Finagler.client[List[Point], Point]("localhost:9000")
```

And call it:

```
client(List(Point(0, 1), Point(1, 1), Point(1, 0), Point(0, 0))).onSuccess(println)
```

Which will print what we'd expect:

```
scala> Point(0.5,0.5)
```

So it seems to work in this simple use case, but I'm not a Netty expert, and I'm curious about ways this naive approach (simply piping everything through a `OneToOneEncoder`, etc.) could get me into trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When decoding a message (i.e. transforming received byte stream into objects), you need to keep in mind that a single socket write is not always translated into a single socket read.

For example, let's say you wrote 4 bytes in a single write attempt.  On the reader's side, it can be read with 2 read attempts where each buffer contains less-than-4-byte data.

Therefore, using `OneToOneDecoder` will not work when your server starts to handler more load.  You need to use other decoder classes such as `FrameDecoder` and `ReplayingDecoder`.

For more information, please read the 'Dealing with a Stream-based Transport' section in the [user guide](http://netty.io/3.9/guide/index.html#start.10).